# AD child domain fails to authenticate when parent domain goes offline

Tags: windows, active-directory

We have several child domains in our forest. All are geographically separated from the parent. One particular child is misbehaving.

When the parent (domain.local) or child (child.domain.local) loses Internet access the clients in the child domain cannot login using accounts within its domain.

Only the child domain administrator account seems to work -- and of course local client accounts. I've checked the child domain DNS settings, and they appear to be the same as other child domains in the forest.

For example, child domain DC IP settings...

```
IP: 10.10.1.100
SN: 255.255.255.0
DNS1: 127.0.0.1
DNS2: 192.168.1.100
```

When the Internet is functioning AD replication and authentication works fine.

Any tips or suggestions on what might be causing this would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by child domain settings?  Are those the DC's settings?

Comment: Server IP settings

Comment: Server IP settings? Which server? Is that your child domain DC?

Comment: Child domain controller, yes.

Comment: OK. it should not be using localhost as it's primary DNS. Does 192.168.1.100 hold a copy of the child domain DNS zone? What is 192.168.1.100? Do you have more than one DC in the child domain?

Comment: 192.168.1.100 is the parent domain DNS.

Comment: @joeqwerty The child domain has only one DC currently.

Comment: Does your child domain have a functioning Global Catalog server?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your misbehaving secondary dns server is pointing to a wrong primary ip address. It should point to 192.168.1.100.

Comment: DNS2 does point there already.

Comment: If your misbehaving server is connected through a VPN connection then it is likely to lost connection to the primary server when the internet is down so you have to make a copy of the the primary server's active directory database to that misbehaving server through replication or some other means.

Comment: How might one do this?